# Ember.js - changes to model in component are not saved

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a pretty simple question about ember components.
I'm defining my model in my route:

```
model() {
  return this.store.createRecord('player');
},
```

I'm passing the model to my component in my template:

```
{{region-picker model=model region="A" regionName=AName teamNameMap=teamNameMap}}
```

Then, inside my component, I can succesfully get the correct data from my model, but nothing that I change in my model is getting sent to the database. I can only assume this is because the model is being passed by value instead of by reference. Is there a way to pass it by reference, and if not, what is the common workaround for editing a model inside of a component.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you u sending your changes to database. show me the code ?. you need to call model.save() to persist to database.

Comment: It's not a database issues. I'm using model.save(). Data that is edited outside of the component successfully saves, but data edited inside the component does not.

Comment: By default its two way binding so it should work afaik. your ember version ?

Comment: 2.7.0. Perhaps I'm doing something else wrong. I'll dig deeper.

Comment: it should work. if not show manipulating model code to your question

Comment: Like mentioned, you _are_ passing by reference. Is this code public? Otherwise it'll be very hard to debug.

Answer (score 1):

the model should be updated, even if you change the data in the component.
Can you verify the same in the EmberJS plugin ? or did you make an explicit copy in the component.

The other thing you might be missing is you need to trigger model.save()
after your component has updated the model.